# Applying NSCheckBox state in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstableview

I have a NSTableView that has two rows, one with checkboxes, one with textfields, and I want to apply the checkbox states from a dictionary in NSTableViewDataSource.viewForTableColumn ...

```
// MARK: - NSTableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView:NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn:NSTableColumn?, row:Int) -> NSView?
{
    var cellView:NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView;
    if (tableColumn!.identifier == "CheckColumn")
    {
        if let themeFlags = getThemeFlagsForCurrentNameType()
        {
            // themeFlags is of type [String:Bool]
            let a = Array(themeFlags);
            let flag:Bool = a[row].1;
            // How to proceed here?
        }
    }
    else if (tableColumn!.identifier == "NameColumn")
    {
        if let d = _themesTableViewData
        {
            let theme = Array(d.keys)[row];
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = theme;
            return cellView;
        }
    }
    return cellView;
}
```

The difficulty I have is how to set the Bool flag to the checkbox wrapped inside the cellView?

Comment: you'll need to make a custom cell view and define an IBOutlet to the checkbox... and then you can access the checkbox through your custom cell view - you may want to look for example at one of the best examples on NSTableView by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727

Comment: Thanks Volker! That's a cleaner solution to what i've now came up with (    let b:NSButton = cellView.subviews.first as! NSButton; b.state = flag ? 1 : 0;) But one question: How can I create an IBOutlet in my CheckBoxTableCellView custom class? IB won't let me connect it.

Comment: you'll need to connect it after you have added your custom clever to your nstableview.. so a bit unexpected place to do that. should be covered in the above linked example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a custom cell view and define an IBOutlet to the checkbox. After adding your custom cell in your `NSTableView`  you can connect the outlets.

To add your custom cell in your table view you can add a normal table cell view and then set its class to your subclass. That gives you access to the outlets you have defined.

Then you can access the checkbox through your custom cell view in code - you may want to look for more details at one of the best examples on NSTableView by Apple: developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/

Also you may want to check in addition this answer [Create a custom cell in a NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112787/create-a-custom-cell-in-a-nstableview) explaining in steps what I have described above.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the ""adding your custom cell in your NSTableView" part? I've set the base class for my checkbox table cell view to be my CheckBoxTableCellView class. Then if I try to control-drag from the checkbox view in the view outline to the class, it still won't let me place an outlet.

Comment: ... It does work if I add an NSObject to my xib and set its base class to be CheckBoxTableCellView. Then IB will make the connection! Just wondering if this is the recommended method of getting this to work?

Comment: Scratch that last comment! It doesn't work that way.

Comment: It still won't work! Even after reading your link. If I write the outlet manually in CheckBoxTableCellView it will let me connect it by dragging over the variable but it then makes it a value binding and if I run this and in my viewForTableColumn() method the checkBox variable is still nil.

Comment: did you take a closer look at TableViewGround example - that should give you some good hints and a working example

Answer (score 1):

The basic NSTableCellView doesn't have any checkbox. Hence the real class of that cellView instance must be, somehow, that of your custom NSTableCellView class. In there, you should have (or put it if you don't) a reference to that checkbox (a NSButton probably).

Hence in your code, you should first make sure the instance you get from `tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(...` is that of your custom class. And at the point where you retrieve your flag, cast your cellView instance to the custom class, access the checkbutton, and set its state.

Comment: I figured it out now. Somehow my UI structure wasn't good. I remade it now with a Storyboard and view controllers properly used in this and now I could successfully make the IBOutlet connection to the checkbox.